# Is there a command to list files, exclude sub-directories and display size and date?

Tags: files, find, directory, ls

Before I begin please assume I have only basic knowledge in UNIX. Basic meaning I have only started reading about it since last week for a work related purpose.

I have been experimenting with the `ls` command to provide lists of a particular directory containing video media. I needed to display the *filename*, *filesize* and the *date* it was created. I achieved this by using the command:

```
ls -gohU
```

This was fine but the search also included the sub-directories within this directory. After searching I found another command which displays the files and excludes the folders:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d
```

What I would like to know is if there is a command that can find all files within the directory excluding sub-directories and display their *filenames*, *size* and the *date* they were created.

P.S. I am also using Terminal - bash on Mac OS 10.6.8 if that helps.

Comment: fwiw Filesystems other than ext4 don't generally record file creation time (I believe this includes HFS+). Bear that in mind when you're interpreting the date. "mtime" is time of last file modification "ctime" is the last time the metadata changed and "atime" is the last access time.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-exec` option to combine both the commands that work for you:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -type d -exec ls -gohU {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

If first character is d then a file is directory. To list lines beginning with other characters use:

```
ls -gohU | grep '^[^d]'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I found this method to work best for what I wanted displayed. I'm very grateful

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to `ls` if you only want some fields is OS/X's `stat` command:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -type d -exec stat -t '%FT%T' -f '%15z %SB %N' {} +
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
command stat -t '%FT%T' -f '%15z %SB %N' -- *(D^/)
```

(`%B`, `ls -U` are OS/X specific, other Unices generally don't have *inode birth times*).

Answer (score 0):

Most versions of find support `-ls` option so the following should give you what you're going for:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -ls
```